# Is it necessary that $A$ be a thick matrix (m < n) for standard form of Linear programming matrix $Ax = b$?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

While looking at the derivation of Linear optimization, I see that it starts by considering standard form; 
$$min(c^T x)$$
$$Ax = b ; \qquad x \ge 0 \qquad b \ge 0$$
Then, it proceeds saying $Without\ Loss\ of\ generality\ rank(A) = m < n $, where, $A$ can be represented as 
$$ [ B\ N ]\ [x_b\ x_n]^T = b $$
$B = m\ x\ m$ and $ N = m\ x\ (n-m)$. Then we consider $B^{-1}$ and so on to proceed towards Simplex Algorithm.

I wanted to know how do we exclude the fact that $A$ can have $m >n $. Or is it possible to convert it back to standard form?

Also, why is it necessary that $A$ has rank $m$?

EDIT: $m$ is number of rows and $n$ is number of columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "thick" ?

Comment: that number of rows are less than number of columns.

Comment: Not usual, nor satisfying, because the transpose of a thick matrix would be a thin matrix. Usually, when a person is thick, he is always thick either on his legs or lying on his bed (in which case, he could be sick as well). I have sometimes seen "portrait matrix" or "landscape matrix" that convey some poetry in an area which is somewhat deprived of humanity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I would avoid using the term now onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^k$ (and therefore $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$).

If $A$ has rank $n$ (and therefore $k\geq n$), there is only one point $x$, that satisfies the linear constraints. It comes down to solving a linear system of equation, which is hardly worthy to be called optimization.

It is impossible to have $rank(A) >n$, since $A$ has a maximum of $n$ collumns.

The only option, that leaves us with an optimization procedure is $rank(A)<n$. You just choose your $m$ accordingly.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. I was thinking something else. It seems elementary now. Thanks.